# How to know whether a device is present or not(present=plugged in) from CoInstaller code?

Tags: winapi

A Windows device CoInstaller function is like this, from Microsoft WDK Toaster sample:

```
extern"C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD CALLBACK
ToasterCoInstaller (
    __in    DI_FUNCTION               InstallFunction,
    __in    HDEVINFO                  Dis,
    __in    PSP_DEVINFO_DATA          Did,  
    __inout PCOINSTALLER_CONTEXT_DATA Context
    )
{
...
}
```

I know that the Dis and Did pair is used to identify a devnode. Even if a device has been unplugged from the system(unplug a USB disk for example), the user may still tell Device Manager to show non-present devices and then our Co-installer may still receive DIS-DID from that unplugged device--because that devnode has been registered in the registry.

So my question is clear, how do I determine from ToasterCoInstaller() whether current DIS-DID refers to a present or non-present device?

One way I can think of is using `SetupDiGetClassDevs` to find all `DIGCF_PRESENT` devnodes and then compare their Device-instance-id to the querying one, if no match found, I can deduce that the querying DIS-DID is not present.

But is there more concise way? Some specific SetupDi... can tell the answer directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use [`CM_Get_DevNode_Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538514(v=vs.85).aspx) and in place third parameter

```
DEVINST dnDevInst
```

use `SP_DEVINFO_DATA.DevInst`

> An opaque handle to the device instance (also known as a handle to the
>   devnode).
>
> Some functions, such as SetupDiXxx functions, take the whole
>   SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure as input to identify a device in a device
>   information set. Other functions, such as CM_Xxx functions like
>   CM_Get_DevNode_Status, take this DevInst handle as input

```
ULONG devStatus, devProblemCode;
switch (CM_Get_DevNode_Status(&devStatus, &devProblemCode, Did->DevInst, 0))
{
case CR_SUCCESS:
    if (devStatus & DN_STARTED)
    {
        //present, started;
    }
    break;
case CR_NO_SUCH_DEVNODE:
    // not present
    break;
default:
    // some error
}
```